# How to make image behave like a checkbox and send its value to backend

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

I want to make an image like a checkbox. (I.e. The picture is a green chair icon. When you press it, it should turn from green to orange, and when pressed again, orange to green.)

The following code works partially, when you click on the green icon, it turns orange, but if I click again to go from orange to green, nothing happens and it stays orange again

The image:

[image]

```
<table style="width:70%">
<tr>
<th>
<center>0</center>
<img src="images/chairgreen.png" id="1"  style="width:64px;height:64px;" onclick="if (src='images/chairgreen.png') { this.src='images/chairorange.png' } else if (src='images/chairorange.png') { this.src='images/chairgreen.png'}" >
</th>
</tr>
```

The problem is the `onclick` method but I don't know how to fix it. And I also don't know how to send the id and the color of the chair to the backend. For the backend I will use java spring.

Comment: This is really simple. Try this - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-toggle-a-boolean-using-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to define class name as color of image. Then you can change the src attribute according to class name. Don't forget to change class name on every click.

```js
function changeImg(img){
if(img.classList.contains("green")){
img.setAttribute("src","images/chairorange.png");
img.classList.remove("green");
img.classList.add("orange");
} 
else if(img.classList.contains("orange")){
img.setAttribute("src","images/chairgreen.png");
img.classList.remove("orange");
img.classList.add("green");
}
}
```

```html
<img src="images/chairgreen.png" id="1" class="green"  style="width:64px;height:64px;" onclick="changeImg(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

don't define functions and run multiple statements when you attach an on click handler.
if you have a complicated thing, write a function and then trigger that one function.

```
<img src="images/chairgreen.png" id="1"  data-src="green" style="width:64px;height:64px;" onclick="change();" >

<script>
function change(e){
    const target = e.target;
    const current = target.getAttribute('data-src');
    switch(current){
      case "green":
        target.src= "images/chairorange.png";
        target.setAttribute('data-src',"orange");
          break;
        case "orange":
        target.src= "images/chairgreen.png";
        target.setAttribute('data-src',"green");
          break;
        default:
          console.error("error", e, current);
            break;
    } 
}

</script>
```

but if you are writing in a script tag, might as well generate the button in js as well

```
const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', "images/chairgreen.png")
  img.setAttribute('id', "1") // use an iterator
  img.setAttribute('data-src', "green");
  img.style.height ="64px";
  img.style.width = "64px";
  img.addEventListener('click', change);
```

you also would need to append to the DOM if you generate elements via js.

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
body.appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing the comparison `if` with only 1 equal sign, you need at least 2 to compare.

```html
onclick="this.src = (this.src == 'images/chairgreen.png') ? 'images/chairorange.png' : 'images/chairgreen.png'"
```